# How to toggle between two divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to toggle between div .cam1 and div .cam2, but nothing is working, heres the code;

HTML:

```
 <div class="cam1"></div>
 <div class="cam2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.cam1 {
position:absolute;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color:red;
}

.cam2 {
position:absolute;
height:100%
width:100%
background-color:blue;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.cam2').hide();
$('.cam1, .cam2').on('click',
    function()
    {
        $('.cam1, .cam2').toggle()
    }
);

$(document).read(main)
```

Comment: When is the jQuery code loaded? On page ready? Or did you put this straight into the `<head>` of the page?

Comment: there is no function `.read` in jQuery, I assume this is a typo? Further whats `main` in this context?

Comment: Using boilerplate, the javascript is placed in the main.js, ignore the .ready and main, im new to javascript/jquery sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dom elements are not loaded when you are trying to hide and bind the event to them. You need to wrap the code in DOM ready event:

```
$(function(){
    $('.cam2').hide();
    $('.cam1, .cam2').on('click',function(){
        $('.cam1, .cam2').toggle();
   });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L6v8634b/)**

Comment: Chrome gives me this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ index.html:31

Comment: Include jQuery. Be sure to do so *before* calling `$`.